# Access to child object in Django relation

Tags: django

*Edit: I would very much like to accomplish this without installing a 3rd-party app. It seems simple/common enough that someone would have posted a line of code that accomplishes this by now?
Couldn't this be done easily in SQL? Would it be taboo to just hit the DB with a custom SQL in the index view?*

So I have a parent Class and 2 child Classes. I would like to query all items and return a quick list.

```
from django.db import models

VIDEO_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('dvd', 'DVD'),
    ('downloaded', 'Downloaded'),
)

BOOK_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('e_book', 'E-Book'),
    ('print', 'Print'),
    ('audio', 'Audio Book'),
)


class Unit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Video(Unit):
    this_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=VIDEO_TYPE_CHOICES, default='dvd')
    run_time = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(Unit):
    this_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BOOK_TYPE_CHOICES, default='print')
    pages = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

All I want to do is display a list of all "Units" with this_type mushed in there on my index page.

Such as:

Lord Of The Rings, lotr.jpeg, DVD

Treasure Island, treasure_island.jpeg, Print

But I only have access to the Units name and image properties if I do a standard "gimme all Units" query...not this_type. Unless of course I make an assumption about the object and try object.book.this_type for example...which throws an exception if that particular object is not a Book.

I've been researching this for a while now...and while I can find several related questions and several possible methods (generic relations, for example?), I cannot find an example that I can relate to my own use case...or understand at all for that matter. I've only been at this stuff (Python and Django) for about a week now...I learn best when I can just make something work, get an understanding of all the moving parts, and then build on that understanding.

In that light, if someone could give me an example of how to generate the previously mentioned object list, I would be extremely grateful!

Pretty PLS???

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the django app [model_utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils)

OOP is generally not the best design pattern for models but if you are going to go that route model_utils has an [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Well...I got it working with InheritanceManager. It seems very "hacky" for lack of a better word, however. I guess it is what it is.

Maybe a future version of Django will do this sort of thing out of the box.

Comment: I doubt it, I think James Bennett in particular is against this design pattern. See http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/feb/20/about-model-subclassing/ and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/uKbPxZ0otNw As for model_utils its a somewhat mature and active app that is used by many (including me) and even recommended in 2scoops of django